# How can I set the installer to use my NFS server instead of a mirror while PXE installing?

Tags: server, nfs, dhcp, tftp

I'm trying to deploy ubuntuer-10.04 server with a pxe server. Now the problem i've encountered is that the netboot initrd/kernel image wants to load ubuntu through a mirror and not through my nfs server. How can i change that to make the installer get the distro through nfs or tftp or whatever from my local server?
And i'm using preseed which i've put in my initrd.

Now it is important to note that i want to install ubuntu server, not to boot it or something similar, and i use a preseeding file. I'm currently using a modified netboot initrd where i've put my preseeding file in.

I've tried the method with netboot=nfs and nfsroot=IPOFMYSERVER:/location/of/my/image/unpacked and this didn't work (worked with ubuntu desktop and it booted but i want to install ubuntu server here).

The problem i have is that the installer keeps aksing for a mirror site and doesn't get the files from my local server

Comment: Can you add to your question if you're using preseed?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation I can find seems to be out of date but it seems setting netboot and nfsroot should do the trick, modify to your needs:

```
netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.0.10:/mnt/u01/tftpboot/ubuntu-desktop
```

Instructions are here:

- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LocalNet
- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveCDNetboot

I have no way to test if this work, so if you cold leave a comment if it worked or not we could keep trying different things.

Comment: this worked when i used ubuntu desktop but i have ubuntu server here and this didn't work actually (i'll give it a second try anyway)

Comment: @Jay can you keep your question updated with what you're trying? Just put your notes right in your question.

Comment: now i've tried this, again, and still doesn't work asks for an ubuntu mirror, (is it important which initrd i use?, cause this was the netboot initrd?)