# PXE install Ubuntu Server using NFS

Tags: server, nfs, pxe

I have Ubuntu 15.04 Live booting from PXE using NFS. Now I am trying to **install** Ubuntu Server 15.04 using same combination of pxelinux and NFS. Installer loads but it is not using *Local Network NFS*, it is asking for *Network Mirror*. Here is entry in my config file:

```
LABEL Ubuntu_Server_15.04_x64
MENU LABEL Ubuntu_Server_15.04_x64
KERNEL /Linux/Ubuntu_Server_15.04_x64/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
APPEND netboot=nfs nfsroot=PXE-SERVER:/linux/Ubuntu_Server_15.04_x64/ initrd=/Linux/Ubuntu_Server_15.04_x64/install/netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz
```

How to make installer use LocalNet NFS instead of Internet mirror?

Comment: Related to http://askubuntu.com/q/89646/26246 .  Never mind I just want to link them.